# Can't stop the "Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer" service on Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-services-client

I just can't stop the "Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer" service.

Please note that I just removed everything related to XConnect from this machine. I'm trying to stop this service to be able to re-install everything.

Keep getting this error message:

```
Windows could not stop the Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - Sitecore901.xconnect-IndexWorker service on Local Computer.

Error: 1061: The service cannot accept control messages at this time.
```

Comment: Are you able to change it from Automatic to Manual before attempting to stop it?

Comment: Tried a reboot? Sounds like it is in a deletion state and a reboot will clear it.

Comment: @ChrisAuer please convert your last comment into an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried a reboot? Sounds like it is in a deletion state and a reboot will clear it.

When you delete a service and it is in state that cannot be removed, it flags it as "To be removed". And it is not until the next reboot that the cleanup job runs to delete the service.

I like to stop the service and run `sc.exe delete [<ServiceName>]` in PowerShell. That seems to work every time for me.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-delete

Comment: TIL this `sc.ex delete myservice` thing, thank you for that Chris!

Comment: Note that one way to get this problem to have is because the services control panel listing all services was open when the service was being removed. Windows likes to keep it around while you have it open, as far as I remember closing that window makes it go away, but i haven’t tried it in a long time.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was also not able to stop the Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer service of my Sitecore 9.0.2 instance. Remember, the **Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer service is very closely related to the Solr cores.** (If the Indexer service is not running, the effect will be that you will not find any contacts (even anonymous/known) getting listed in the Experience Profile when any visitor visits your website (Or) you cant delete any contact from any list in the List Manager)

When I checked the Solr service, I found that it was in the **Paused** state, I was not able to stop this Solr service. Then, I realized that the problem was with this Solr. ***This Solr service was running in the same port that the other Solr Service was running.*** So, I stopped the other service, then I resumed this Solr Service (that my Sitecore instance is now using). Then, I was able to stop/start the Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer service as usual.

**Two things to remember always:**

1. the Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer service is very closely related to the Solr cores.

2. Never create a Solr service with the same port number specified for another Solr service. Or the best recommended way is that you give a Service name along with the port number for avoiding confusions, for example, SOLR721HOST8985

**NOTE:**
Both services were of the same Solr version 6.6.2